# How to add .xib file for iPad in an application that was previously built for iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode5

I've an application for iPhone. At first we were not planning to release it for iPad. But now we want it available for iPad. I've searched enough for that but didn't find any good way to add .xib for iPad.

I know there are other way to change it to support iPad. In Xcode my projects **Targeted Device Family is iPhone/iPad**. The app now runs on iPad, But I want to add different iPad .xib for each view. How can I add different .xib for iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here.

1.) Use auto-layout to try to use the .xib files to layout/space correctly on the iPad.

OR

2.) Create new .xib files for the iPad specifically and every time you instantiate a view controller load the correct xib file based on the device type

```
ViewController *vc;
if (iPhone)
{
   vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPhoneNIB" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
   vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPadNIB" bundle:nil];
}
```